# "She isn't a movie-going person"

Tags: grammaticality, participles

What does "movie-going" mean in this phrase? Can we use the same for other locations like the theater or the stadium?

> She isn't a movie-going person

Source:
https://twitter.com/tvs_movies/status/1224530855709827073

Answer (score 1):

Quite simply, 'She isn't a movie-going person' means that she rarely goes to the cinema or theatre.

Not to be confused with something like, 'She isn't a dog person' which has connotations of not actually liking dogs.

You can like films/movies but not be a 'movie going person', and yes, you can use the same for other locations.